# php content type header with windows expression encoder 4

Tags: php

i run windows expression encoder 4 stream with url http://127.0.0.1:8080
i want users to play with my customurl http://127.0.0.1/stream.php
so, i've try this code but no luck.

```
<?php
$fullPath = 'http://10.20.204.110:8080';
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fullPath)."\";" );
readfile($fullPath);
?>
```

Comment: give it a correct file name. `filename=stream.flv` for example

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a lot to relay through a small PHP script as such. If you're using Apache, I'd recommend [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). You could do something like this in your vhost.conf file without invoking the overhead of PHP:

```
ProxyPass /stream http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

Comment: +1 You really shouldn't occupy a PHP instance with relaying a stream.

Comment: actually i want to authenticate the user

Comment: Apache has authentication modules (including those with support for LDAP, MySQL and more).

Comment: so, is it impossible to do in PHP ?

Comment: @rails It's not impossible, but PHP is really not the ideal language to be tied up for a long time relaying a stream. That's what streaming servers are made for, not a *Hypertext Preprocessor*. Since the client needs to handle authentication as well, a compatible streaming server should offer authentication too.